# Changing @ record breaks email?

Tags: email, dns

I recently updated the @ record of a website and nothing else so as not to interrupt their emails.  I'm somewhat familiar with DNS settings but when it comes to emails I'm pretty lacking in knowledge.  Anyways, after updating the @ record my client could no longer receive emails.  They are able to send, however.  The new website itself is on another server (which I pointed the @ record to), while the emails and (old) website are on another.  I specifically set the new web server's email to Remote.

Is this just an issue with propagation?  It was changed a day ago and everything else went smoothly.

Comment: What are your MX records?

Comment: Have you changed `CNAME` DNS record?

Comment: I have not altered the CNAME records.  Here are the records for the domain itself:

https://screenshots.firefox.com/sFBKSMUnpdanIMpQ/my.justhost.com

Here are the WHM DNS settings for where the new website is held:

https://screenshots.firefox.com/OiS0AABpkkRCYFt9/162.254.252.207

Answer (score 0):

You must check the MX records for the domain in DNS zone. They should point to the correct server for ensuring to receive emails.

Comment: I left the MX records alone for the domain.  I'm thinking I may need to make some changing from where the website itself is stored, as there are DNS settings there as well.   Here are the records for the domain itself (only changed the @ record): https://screenshots.firefox.com/sFBKSMUnpdanIMpQ/my.justhost.com 

Here are the WHM DNS settings for where the new website is held: https://screenshots.firefox.com/OiS0AABpkkRCYFt9/162.254.252.207

Comment: in the MX section, change the points to column value to the old server ip address where you want to receive emails.

Comment: It's not possible to set an MX record to an IP.

Comment: I was able to get this working by changing the MX to point to mail.domain.com.  For whatever reason when I changed the @ record it must have also changed the MX record to just domain.com, which I know I didn't touch.  So far the emails are working again.